# shell script for easing tasks of System Administrators

Tags: shell-script

I am planning to develop a Menu Driven script that would enable a system administrator to perform the daily duties with an ease .

For eg. 1. Check and Troubleshoot NTP Issues
        2. Check and Troubleshoot NFS ISsues
        3. Install .rpm package
        4. Disk space utilization 
        5. Check Memory Leak
        6. High CPU Utilization
        7.

Help needed from the forum members
1. Can you please suggest whether such a script/program already exists
2. Would such a script be of an use to the System Administrator
3. What functions/options can be included in the script

Answer (score 1):

There are, of course, many bash scripts on the 'net that folks use for checking NTP/NFS issues.  Without seeing at least a rudimentary rough draft of the script, it would be hard to say just how useful something like this might be.  Are you thinking of readline's with if/then & case statements to implement such a script?  I can't speak for other sysadmins, but I like separating out tasks such as installing RPM's instead of rolling it into scripts because of the ability to view, real-time, what might have failed such as dependency issues.  With yum becoming more stable, I believe most of us are utilizing that path first, then individual RPM's only when no alternative exists.  I think it might make more sense for you to define your goal a bit more thoroughly to the audience before useful feedback can be given.

Comment: my goal is to acheive similar to the below menu options

Comment: my goal is to achieve similar to the below menu options       , also please note that I wish to have this script portable in all the flavours of Linux/UNIX - mainly AIX/HPUX/Solaris and RHEL

Comment: System Administration Menu
1. User Administration  [useradd/userdel/passwd/user unlock etc ..]
2. Access a Console  [a text file based database that provides information about accessing consoles]
3. Analyze Hardware Failures [identify hardisk/DIMM/Fan failures etc]
4. Disk Space Utilization [identify the highly utilizing directories]
5. CPU Utilization  [identify the processes that are using high CPU resource]
6. Network Services  [identify current status and if any issue found try to find the underlying cause]
 6.1. NFS
 6.2. NTP
 6.3. Samba etc  
7.